# Generic task for get list of objects from api

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

im building some solution in blazor
i want to have generic way to 'speak' with my api to get list of SomeClassT like this

```
  await api.ExecProcGetList<SomeClassT>(
        (list) =>
        {
            foreach (item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        },
        (msg) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error" + msg);
        }
     );
```

so in this api service i have

```
  public  Task ExecProcGetList<T>(Action<List<T>> callback, Action<string> callbackOnFailed = null)
    {
        return  Task.Factory.StartNew(async (n)=>
        {
            string endpoint = "sp/t/" + this.dbName + "/" + this.schema + "/" + this.procName;
            var response = await this.httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(endpoint, this.parameters);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                 callback(  await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<T>>());               
            }
            else
            {
                if (callbackOnFailed != null) callbackOnFailed(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
                else Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
            }

        }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    }
```

I see that list is taken from api as should, but i get list of my items of this SomeClassT with empty values.

property names are ok so i guess this T is not rightly passed to this task?

how should i fix that?
thanks and regards

---

edit

```
class SomeClassT
{
    public int ID
    public int IDSiec;
}
```

raw response

`[{"ID":11401174,"IDSiec":1380},{"ID":11411073,"IDSiec":300},{"ID":11401172,"IDSiec":1308}]`

Comment: Please add the raw response of the api to the question and also the definition of the class you try to deserialize to.

Comment: And `ReadFromJsonAsync` does not throw anything or something like this?

Comment: The `Task.Run` is the preferred way to offload work to a background thread. If you want to use the `Task.Factory.StartNew` with an async delegate for some reason, you need to `Unwrap()` it at the end. Look [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) for the reasons why. As a side note, you should avoid blocking the current thread by reading the `.Result` property of a task. This is why `await` exists after all.

Comment: ExecProcGetList should be marked with `async` keyword if await is inside

Comment: Theodor Zoulias thanks for article i didnt knew that ;) and i known that should always await just wanted to change this after main feature is ok ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks all for tips but none of them was right
the problem was that i was missing

```
{ get; set; }
```

in class fields
with this is fine.